# Woocommerce Product Price Inserted programmatically doesn't get displayed In Single Product Page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to scrape a price with simple html DOM and set it as regular product price in Woocommerce.

Here is my actual code:

```
//Starting scrape
$html = file_get_html('http://sitenam.com/page-1/');
$price = $html->find('span[class="price"]', 0)->innertext;
//Starting post
$post = array(
    'post_author' => 1,
    'post_content' => 'Content Here',
    'post_status' => "publish",
    'post_title' => "Product Title Here",
    'post_parent' => "product-title-here",
    'post_type' => "product",
);

$post_id = wp_insert_post( $post, $wp_error ); 

wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'simple', 'product_type' );  

add_post_meta( $post_id, '_regular_price', $price );
```

The product price is really saved as you can see in this image:

[image: Product Price]

But the real problem is that the product price is not displayed on front end. Here's the screenshot:

[image: Product Price Not showing]

Now on admin edit product page, if I click on "update" button, then the price is displayed on frontend product pages.

How can I automate this process from my code, without going in backend saving the product data?

Comment: Are you trying to reinstalling the plugin and theme?

Comment: Yes, I tried it also bro...

Comment: are you Test your website in another theme, is it work properly or not,    Are you install any third-party plugin like paytm ,sometimes its causes this type of problem,  when i face this problem i just wipe my site and reinstall all the thinks ,       you try this ,Open your site’s wp-config file and add define( 'WC_REMOVE_ALL_DATA', true); on its own line above the /*

Comment: It's not worked bro. I tried everything :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following using the `WC_Product` Object and methods instead:

```
// Starting scrape
$html = file_get_html('http://sitenam.com/page-1/');

$price = (float) $html->find('span[class="price"]', 0)->innertext;

// Saving the new product
$post_id = wp_insert_post( array(
    'post_author' => 1,
    'post_content' => 'Content Here',
    'post_status' => "publish",
    'post_title' => "Product Title Here",
    'post_parent' => "product-title-here",
    'post_type' => "product",
) ); 

// Setting the product type
wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'simple', 'product_type' );  

// Get the WC_Product Object instance
$product = wc_get_product( $post_id );

// Set the product active price (regular)
$product->set_price( $price );
$product->set_regular_price( $price ); // To be sure

// Save product data (sync data and refresh caches)
$product->save();
```

This time the product price should be displayed in front end.

Comment: Thank you so much... It worked... Love you bro